# Making my output be an 8-bit output from a pre-defined array

Tags: arrays, verilog

I'm trying to make a program that  works like an up-down counter as it reads values from an array equivalent to what the counter is at, where this counter value can be adjusted whether the up or down function is active. This is my code below, where I have excluded my 1_Hz counter that already has proven to work. The errors I receive so far during synthesis is that **mem** has not been declared and I am unsure how to fix that. Advice appreciated, thank you.

```
module reader    (
output reg  [7:0] out      ,  // Output of the counter
input  wire       up_down  ,  // up_down control for counter
input  wire       clk_1Hz      ,  // clock input
input  wire       reset       // reset input
mem
);

//-------------Code Starts Here-------

reg [16:0] i;
reg [7:0][0:16] mem;
initial begin
assign {mem[0],mem[1],mem[2],mem[3],mem[4],mem[5],mem[6],mem[7],mem[8],mem[9],mem[10],mem[11],mem[12],mem[13],mem[14],mem[15],mem[16]}={8'b0000000,8'b00000001,8'b00000100,8'b00001001,8'b00010000,8'b00011001,8'b00100100,8'b00110001,8'b01000000,8'b01010001,8'b01101000,8'b01111001,8'b10010000,8'b10101001,8'b11000100,8'b11100001,8'b11111111};
end

always @(posedge clk_1Hz)

if (reset) begin // active high reset
  out <= 8'b0 ;
end else if (up_down) begin
    i <= i+1;
  out <=  mem[i];
end else begin
    i <= i-1;
  out <=mem[i];
end 
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

initial blocks are not synthesizable, try below code.

```
module reader    (
output reg  [7:0] out      ,  // Output of the counter
input  wire       up_down  ,  // up_down control for counter
input  wire       clk_1Hz      ,  // clock input
input  wire       reset       // reset input
 //  mem   //Removed this from port list
);

//-------------Code Starts Here-------

reg [4:0] i;  //Address range is 0-16 hence only 5 bits needed
reg [7:0]mem[16:0]; //2-D wire declaration

always@(*) begin {mem[0],mem[1],mem[2],mem[3],mem[4],mem[5],mem[6],mem[7],mem[8],mem[9],mem[10],mem[11],mem[12],mem[13],mem[14],mem[15],mem[16]}={8'b0000000,8'b00000001,8'b00000100,8'b00001001,8'b00010000,8'b00011001,8'b00100100,8'b00110001,8'b01000000,8'b01010001,8'b01101000,8'b01111001,8'b10010000,8'b10101001,8'b11000100,8'b11100001,8'b11111111};
end

 always @(posedge clk_1Hz)
 begin
   if (reset) begin // active high reset
     out <= 8'b0 ;
   end 
   else if (up_down) 
   begin
     i   <= i+1;
     out <=  mem[i];
   end 
   else 
   begin
    i   <= (i == 0) ? i : i-1; //Added cond to avoid underflow
    out <= mem[i];
   end
  end 

 endmodule
```

Comment: There's an error when synthesizing on line 32 "No signals referenced in statement with implicit sensitivity list". This is the always@(*), which should work but for some reason it isn't working for me.

Comment: Then bring the mem assignemnt out of the always* block and use
assign {mem[0],mem[1],mem[2],mem[3],mem[4],mem[5],mem[6],mem[7],mem[8],mem[9],mem[10],mem[11],mem[12],mem[13],mem[14],mem[15],mem[16]}={8'b0000000,8'b00000001,8'b00000100,8'b00001001,8'b00010000,8'b00011001,8'b00100100,8'b00110001,8'b01000000,8'b01010001,8'b01101000,8'b01111001,8'b10010000,8'b10101001,8'b11000100,8'b11100001,8'b11111111};